# sql server settings for connection via windows 7

Tags: c#, sql, database

My program was working on Windows XP with Windows Server 2003 and Framework 4.0 without any problem. We use Windows 7 on computers anymore, we are getting an error about login failed now when the program try to connect database. Should I change something on client or server, could you help me?

Error message is:

```
Login failed. the login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows authentication

Bu iletişim kutusu yerine JIT hata ayıklamayı çağırma hakkında detaylı bilgi için bu iletinin sonuna bakın.

************** Özel Durum Metni ************** System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.    konum: System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    konum: System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    konum: System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    konum: System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    konum: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)    konum: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)    konum: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    konum: stokKontrol.Form1.dbBaglan() C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\stokKontrol\stokKontrol\Form1.cs içinde: satır 291    konum: stokKontrol.Form1.cariOtoDoldur() C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\stokKontrol\stokKontrol\Form1.cs içinde: satır 44    konum: stokKontrol.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\stokKontrol\stokKontrol\Form1.cs içinde: satır 1370    konum: System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)    konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    konum: System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    konum: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam) ClientConnectionId:824f06ba-5b8e-455a-9ef8-e53dfe23608c Error Number:18452,State:1,Class:14


************** Yüklü Derlemeler ************** mscorlib
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
---------------------------------------- stokKontrol
    Derleme Sürümü: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file://Gunes/d$/gunluk_rapor/addOns/bltBin/stokKontrol/stokKontrol/bin/Debug/stokKontrol.exe
---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34251 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34270 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
---------------------------------------- System
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34238 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_tr_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Configuration
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Xml
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34234 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Data
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Transactions
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
---------------------------------------- System.EnterpriseServices
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
---------------------------------------- mscorlib.resources
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_tr_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Data.resources
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_tr_b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.resources.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Hata Ayıklama ************** JIT hata ayıklamayı etkinleştirmek için, bu uygulamanın veya bilgisayarın (machine.config) .config dosyasında system.windows.forms bölümünde jitDebugging değeri ayarlanmış olmalıdır. Ayrıca uygulama hata ayıklama etkin durumdayken derlenmiş olmalıdır.

Örneğin:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" /> </configuration>

JIT hata ayıklama etkinken, işlenmemiş özel durumlar bu iletişim kutusunda işlenmek yerine bilgisayarda kayıtlı JIT hata ayıklayıcısına gönderilir.
```

Comment: Please provide connection string the client uses to connect.  When the program runs, under what user account is it running?  Is it definitely a domain user?

Comment: I use this string for connection. conString = "Server=GNS; Database = GNSdatabase;User ID= user;Password= 123456;Trusted_Connection=true"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem after change my connection string

from
conString = "Server=GNS; Database = GNSdatabase;User ID= user;Password= 123456;Trusted_Connection=true"

to
conString = "Server=GNS; Database = GNSdatabase;User ID= user;Password= 123456"

I didn't know that, Trusted_Connection is used for only windows authentication. When I delete this, the program worked clearly.